# Download a file when clicking a button

Tags: javascript

For some reason, this code will not download a file when clicked. And No Error pops up.

why and how do I fix it?

```
  var element = document.createElement("a");
  element.setAttribute(
    "href",
    "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(text)
  );
  element.setAttribute("download", filename);

  element.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function () {
    // Generate download of hello.txt file with some content
    var text = document.getElementById("text-val").value;
    var filename = "hello.txt";

    download(filename, text);
  },
  false
```